# How do I row reduce a matrix mod 26 when it is singular mod 26?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Cryptography assignment question: matrix $A$ is 
\begin{equation}
A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
             1 & 0 & 0 \\
             1 & 3 & 1 \\
             0 & 2 & 5 \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
(Hill Cipher key). Show that for a vector $x_1$, $x_1A=x_2A \mod 26$ for exactly $13$ $x_2$'s.

Progress so far:   $\det(A)=13$ so $A$ is not invertible $\mod 26$. Re-write the problem as find $y$ such that $yA=0 \mod 26$. I thought I could find $y$ by finding the null space of $A$ $\mod 26$ but I don't know how to do that. It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that re-arranged it as (x1-x2)A=0 mod 26 and let (x1-x2)=y so there should be 13 different y vectors such that yA=0 mod 26

Answer (score 1):

So, $A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\1&3&1\\0&2&5}$ and let $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$. Then we need to find the solutions of $yA=0$, i.e.
$$\matrix{y_1+y_2 &=& 0 &&& (i) \\
3y_2+2y_3 &=& 0  &&& (ii)\\
y_2+5y_3 &=& 0 &&& (iii)
}$$
Now perform $(ii)\,-\,3\cdot(iii)$ to obtain $\ \ -13y_3=0 \quad\quad (iv)$. 
Since all these are modulo $26$, any *even* $y_3\in\Bbb Z_{26}$ will be a solution 
of $(iv)$. (There are exactly $13$ even numbers modulo $26$.) 
Then, $y_2$ can be uniquely determined by either $(iii)$ or $(ii)$, knowing the choice for $y_3$ and also, $y_2$ determines $y_1$ by $(i)$.